# t4 template processing finding another copy of EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, t4

I have an issue where, when I run a T4 template, it is picking up another copy of the EntityFramework.dll in the VS Common7 folder. That causes it to think that my DbContext class does not inherit from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

When I debug the T4 template I get the following in the Immediate window.

```
typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbContext).Module.FullyQualifiedName
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\EntityFramework.dll"
```

However that path is absolutely nowhere in my Modules window. The proper EntityFramework.dll shows up there from my build output for the project I'm referencing.

I understand I'm leaving out some detail here, and I'll fill in more to answer questions, but I am just at a total loss as to what would cause Visual Studio to pull in another EntityFramework.dll instead of using the one that I'm providing it. This all runs fine, by the way, if I directly run the code in a command line app or if I set the templating tool to TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor and run the generated class.

The line of code this is all erroring on is:

```
Database.SetInitializer<FakeDbContext>(null);
```

FakeDbContext being nothing more than:

```
public class FakeDbContext: DbContext
{

}
```

The error I get is, given the dll issue, predictable:

> Method System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer: type argument
>   'FakeT4Dependencies.FakeDbContext' violates the constraint of type
>   parameter 'TContext'.

It thinks FakeDbContext is not a DbContext. Which it thinks because of the dll issue. Interestingly, the issue is a run time error, not an error at compilation of the text transform class. I can tell that by the stack trace, the type of exception (`VerificationException`), and the fact that it's an exception and not a compile error.

If I run the code straight through my command line, by the way, you get what you would expect for the type. And everything works fine.

```
typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbContext).Module.FullyQualifiedName
"C:\\Users\\jeffreyvest\\Code\\TestT4Dependencies\\TestT4Dependencies\\bin\\Debug\\EntityFramework.dll"
```

The issue only comes up when running it through the custom tool by saving the .tt file. Somehow VS loads things up just a bit differently and it wants to go off and use a different copy of the dll that I do not want it using at all. Incidentally, that copy is the same version of EntityFramework.dll. Just the fact that it lives in another assembly, and not the one referenced by my code, is throwing it off. The deepest mystery for me is the fact that it does not show that dll anywhere in my module list. It shows the other copy in my bin/debug of the project whose output I'm using. So it appears that's all getting bound up correctly then suddenly at the last minute somehow the type itself gets associated to a different dll. It would even be ok if it used nothing but that other dll in Common7 folder. It's the mix that's making it all go wonky.

**EDIT**

As an added fun twist, changing the assembly referenced in the T4 to use that Common7 copy of EntityFramework fixes the issue **only when debugging the T4**. When running it straight (just saving the .tt file) it still has the issue described.

I also put this together that I think really illustrates the issue.

```
typeof(FakeT4Dependencies.FakeDbContext).BaseType.Module.FullyQualifiedName
"C:\\Users\\jeffreyvest\\Code\\TestT4Dependencies\\FakeT4Dependencies\\bin\\Debug\\EntityFramework.dll"
typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbContext).Module.FullyQualifiedName
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\EntityFramework.dll"
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a dummy project to see if the problem persists outside of your project?  That might give you some different error that might help.  Also are you adding any [assemble directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx) for the System.Data.Entity dll?  Maybe adding one to explicitly set the location of the EF dll you want to use might help. And just for the sake of trying, maybe setting the [cleanup behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495329.aspx) might help.